# responsive spacing (i.e. mb-lg-2 mb-sm-3 etc) not working in Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

In bootstrap 4 these classes were working fine. But they are not working in Bootstrap 5. Any idea why?

Note: **d-block d-lg-flex** , **text-center text-lg-start text-md-end** these are working fine. Looks like just margin and padding related classes are not working.

Sample code:

```
 <div class="d-block d-lg-flex justify-content-center flex-row bd-highlight ">
    <div class="mb-0 mb-md-3 mb-lg-0">
        <div class="dropdown text-center cairo ">
            <select x-model="selectedUnits" class="form-select feature_text" aria-label="Default select example">
                <option selected="" disabled="">Select unit amount</option>
                <option value="myval">1 unit</option>
                <option value="myval">1 unit</option>
                <option value="myval">1 unit</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The margin classes `mb-0 mb-md-3 mb-lg-0` should work as expected in both Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 5.

[Responsive margin bottom working in Bootstrap 5](https://codeply.com/p/T6GQ3VacyI)

However `text-lg-left text-md-right` has changed to `text-lg-start text-md-end` in Bootstrap 5

Comment: mb-xs-2 is not working.

Comment: no...  `mb-xs-2` would not work because it doesn't exist in Bootstrap 4 or 5

Answer (score 1):

## 2021 in **bootstrap 5** Margin and Padding :

**Margin**

- Margin Margin top: mt-value
- Margin right: me-value
- Margin bottom: mb-value
- Margin left: ms-value

**Padding**

- Padding top: pt-value
- Padding right: pe-value
- Padding bottom: pb-value
- Paddig left: ps-value.

The range for the value is 0 to 5(Ex:- pt-1 for Padding top)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answers here, the margin classes `mb-0 mb-md-3 mb-lg-0` work as expected.

For `xs` we need to give the margin and padding like `{property}{sides}-{size}` as `{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}` works for `sm, md, lg, xl`, and `xxl`.

As mentioned [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/)